# How can I capture the contents of one or more strings using a regex?

Tags: .net, regex

**Let's say I have the following three strings:**

(section1){stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all}

(section1)(section2){stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all}

(section1)(section2)(section3){stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all}

**So if applied regex to my expressions, for the first I would get:**

section1

stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all

**if applied regex to my expressions, for the second I would get:**

section1

section2

stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all

**and if applied regex to my expressions, for the third I would get:**

section1

section2

section3

stuff could be any character, i want to grab it all

**I have the following regex:**

((?<section>.+))+{?<term>.+}

So look for inside parens and repeat and then what's inside the curly brackets.
It doesn't seem to work
Any clue? This has always been my Achille's heel.

Comment: what flavor of Regex are you using?  Perl?  JavaScript? .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<section>\(.+?\))+?(?<term>\{.+\})
```

is probably closer to what you're looking for.

This will match however many (section*N*) segments you have, along with the {term}

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you wanted very well, but I'll try to answer anyway

```
(\(section1\)(\(section2\)(\(section3\))?)?)(.*)
```

That will match (and capture) (section1) followed by something else (or nothing) and optionally followed by a (section2) that could, in turn, be optionally followed by (section3)

I'm almost certain this isn't what you need, but at least will prompt you to describe your question better :-)

Comment: Yeah, I explained it poorly:

There could be anywhere from 1 to 16 (sectionX) fields in front of my {.....}

I want to capture all the ones there whther i get a string with 1 section or 16.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to keep in mind as well when writing your regex, the occurance  braces {} contain numbers, not wild cards.

```
 <regex>{3}  //will match three exactly
 <regex>{0,3} // will match up to and including three
 <regex>{3,} // will match three or more
```

it is also nice to have a utility to test your strings out while trying to compose your pattern.  here is [one such online tool](http://www.rubular.com/)